# "Compile error: Block If Without End If"

Tags: vba, excel

First, I have used my eyes and Ctrl+F and another person's eyes to check for End If, I do not see why I get this error message:

> Compile error: Block If Without End If

I have tried to indent macro correctly, hope it is clear to read.

This is the entire function since I am not sure where the error message is. The compiler selects the End Sub at the very end of this function.

```
Sub settings()
'   Goal of this function: to get user-desired settings and request permission to clear sheet
'   could write these settings to text file and create profiles so that user can skip entering all this every time?
Dim cases As Variant
Dim title As String
title = "K-Map Program"
cases = InputBox("Enter number of inputs.", title)
If Not IsNumeric(cases) Then
    Call notnum
End If
clearsheet = MsgBox("Permission to clear Sheet1?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, title) ' could upgrade by giving user choice of which sheet to clear
If clearsheet = vbYes Then
    MsgBox ("Clearing sheet1.")
    Sheet1.Cells.Clear
ElseIf clearsheet = vbNo Then
    MsgBox ("Sheet1 has not been cleared, program is ending.")
    Exit Sub
Else
    Call errormessage
End If
numforswitch = MsgBox("Do you want to label the inputs as numbers (1, 2, 3...)?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, title)
'   deposit the switches in columns in 0, 1 format
If numforswitch = vbYes Then
    ifshift = MsgBox("Shift=0?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, title)
    If ifshift = vbYes Then
        For counter = 1 To cases
            Cells(1, counter).Value2 = counter ' will print 1, 2, 3... in the columns
        Next
    ElseIf shift = vbNo Then
        shift = InputBox("What's shift?")
        For counter = 1 To cases
            Cells(1, counter).Value2 = counter + shift ' will print x, x+1...
        Next
ElseIf numforswitch = vbNo Then
    MsgBox ("Using letters for switches.")
'       alphabet array
    Const ALPHABET As String = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 1 To VBA.Len(ALPHABET)
        Cells(1, i).Value = VBA.Mid(ALPHABET, i, 1)
    Next i
    Else
        Call errormessage
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your missing end-if is in this block:

```
If ifshift = vbYes Then
    For counter = 1 To cases
        Cells(1, counter).Value2 = counter ' will print 1, 2, 3... in the columns
    Next
ElseIf shift = vbNo Then
    shift = InputBox("What's shift?")
    For counter = 1 To cases
        Cells(1, counter).Value2 = counter + shift ' will print x, x+1...
    Next
```

You should cleanup/format your code so you can easily spot issues like this.  If you don't make your code look nice and orderly, you'll waste a lot of time with problems like this.

Comment: How can I make my code more orderly? I have tried to do this, thank you for any tips you might have.

Comment: @ThomasShera One point is that you are doing many different tasks within a single sub - you should try to compartmentalize all tasks into new subs, which you then call in order from the 'main' sub. This makes each section of code more isolated [less prone to lengthy searches for problems], and also makes it easier to reuse code sections when you perform repetitive tasks throughout the program.

Comment: For better improvement of your code, post it on the code review : http://codereview.stackexchange.com - plenty of good ideas over there. ElseIf I've always found unreadable(select Case does wonders instead in terms of readability) You can also jump a few lines to see better paragraphs.

Comment: @gazzz0x2z -- ElseIf has its place.  You can't compare object reference equality with select case.  Also, if you want to compare strings without regard to case, you'd have to at the very least synchronize the case of the strings being compared.